# scan multiple pages using the scan button on DCP-7065DN and xsane

Tags: scanner, brother, xsane

[image]I have a Brother DCP7065DN scanner/printer and I'm running xsane under Kubuntu 14.04.  I have several pages to scan.  I want to be able to initiate the scan of each page from the scanner using its SCAN button rather than from the program.  That's so I don't have to run back and forth from the scanner to the computer.  Is that possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for xsane 0.999 in Debian, with an [Epson Perfection 3200 Photo](https://epson.com/Support/Scanners/Perfection-Series/Epson-Perfection-3200-Photo/s/SPT_B11B156011) scanner. It also has a dedicated scan button which I wanted to use for scanning multiple pages.

There should be no changes to this from version 0.998 in Kubuntu 14.04.

The "trick" is to increase the **Number of pages to scan**, open the **Advanced options** window, and enable **Wait for Button**. Setting the number of pages to something much larger than the number you plan to scan should be fine.

The page numbers will be auto-incremented, and xsane will scan *N* pages, waiting for the button before each page.

[image]

Comment: @PaulA. Maybe the SANE backend driver does not understand that your scanner even _has_ a button? If it doesn't, I don't think xsane can do much about it :/

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested, but the only advanced options I can find have to do with the geometry.  I'm running xsane 0.998.  I tried to attach a screenshot showing my xsane window but I couldn't figure out how to add a screenshot to a comment.

Comment: @PaulA. That's ok, I've flagged so a mod can delete them, unless you can do it on your side - I don't remember when you can delete comments. You can attach a screenshot to your original question, that could perhaps be helpful

Comment: I attached the screenshot to the original post, as you suggested.

Comment: Paul: do you not have to add the "scan-key-tool" that Brother supply http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn3.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&redirect=on as I had thought was to enable you to use the scan button on the device . This page http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn5.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&redirect=on give more info:

Comment: I had set aside this problem but it remains unsolved.  I have installed brscan-skey-tool  as advised.  However, "brscan-skey -l" does not find the scanner even though the scanner is working.  I can use the scanner with xsane but I can't activate the scan button on the scanner.